# What's the biggest time gap between authorship of two books of the Bible?

Tags: bible, chronology

What's the biggest time gap between authorship of two books of the Bible?

Honestly, I don't even know the order in which the books of the Bible were written, but I am quite interested in what the longest period of time that elapsed between two authorship of two books of the Scriptures.

Comment: Are you asking about the chronology of the writing of the books, or the chronology of the content of the books?

Comment: Actually, having read this question of yours, I am quite confused now. Has it been like the content of a book would depict a time that was already way a past time during the time of writing? If so, then I would probably want to have a question in both dimensions, so to say. Which dimension, by the way, is it in the answer by Sven given below? Is it a dimension of time of writing or the one of the time of the content?

Comment: Of course... Most of the books of the Bible are written as history, so the chronology they portray happened well before the books were written. Genesis is the most extreme example, including a history since the beginning of the world. And some say Revelation is about the _future_ -- if true it was written 2000+ years _before_ the events took place. At any rate, many think Job was the first book of the Bible written, but chronologically it obviously portrays events that occurred _after_ Genesis.

Comment: And @Sven's answer is talking about the chronology of writing, not the chronology of events portrayed in the writing.

Comment: @Flimzy - Then I am after the chronology of the writing of the books.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last book of the Old Testament, Malachi, was written about 443 B.C.  The first book of the New Testament, Matthew, was written about 40 A.D. leaving a 500 year gap between the Old and New Testament books.

Second would be Joshua (~1450 BC) and Judges (written by Samuel ~1100 BC)

Comment: I think your dating of the "Gospel of Matthew" is too conservative. Given that estimates for the dates when the canonical gospel accounts were written vary significantly among scholars; and the evidence for any of the dates is scanty. So I ask: What is the source of your claim? How reliable is the source of the claim? Has the claim been verified by somebody else? Has anyone tried to disprove the claim?

Comment: @monocode, you're the second who questioned the date and I'll look into it more. I didn't know, but apparently the dates range from 40-100 AD.. I think it's a bit unrelevant to that question so I think maybe this should be asked as a own question.

Comment: You are, of course, ignoring Maccabees.